# Show dialog box programmatically, then dispose it on dialog button press

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, material-design

I currently have a UserControl View and ViewModel which essentially gets some data back about the user. If the user does not have access rights to the system, the application should show a pop up box telling the user this information - the popup box has an "OK" button, which then disposes the dialog box and returns to the previous user control.

I am also using Material Design to do this, however implementation is not very clear from the documentation here: https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs#dialoghostshow

My implementation is as follows:

Dialog View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GiveUpRegister.Dialogs.MessageBoxView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Height="auto" Width="auto">

    <materialDesign:Card HorizontalAlignment="Center" materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth1">
        <DockPanel  Height="auto" Width="250">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TxtBlockTitle.Value}" FontWeight="Bold" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="20,20,9,20">Example error title</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TxtBlockMessage.Value}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="20,5,20,10">Some error message.</TextBlock>
            <Button Margin="9,10,9,10" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
                OK
            </Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </materialDesign:Card>
</UserControl>
```

Dialog ViewModel:

```
public class MessageBoxViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private bool _isMessageBoxOpen;
    public bool IsMessageBoxOpen
    {
        get => _isMessageBoxOpen;
        set
        {
            if (_isMessageBoxOpen == value) return;
            _isMessageBoxOpen = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsMessageBoxOpen));
        }
    }

    private object _messageContent;
    public object MessageContent
    {
        get => _messageContent;
        set
        {
            if (_messageContent == value) return;
            _messageContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MessageContent));
        }
    }


    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

How do I adapt this code to be able to initialise this from the following code:

StartupViewModel:

```
private async Task LoadUserDetails()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SystemUserService = SystemUserService.Instance);
        bool hasAccess = SystemUserService.CheckAccessPermission();
        if (hasAccess)
        {
             // Show the dialog box
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.SendError("Could not retrieve user details", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've flagged this as MVVM, in which case you might want to look at [the CodeProject article and library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM) I developed for doing just this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks promising. I haven't tried it, but this appears to open the dialog and then waits for a user to click a button. I took this from their site under Close Strategies.

```
var result = await DialogHost.Show(myControl, delegate(object sender, 
DialogOpenedEventArgs args)
{
    args.Session.Close(false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to wait for a dialogbox without blocking the calling UI thread.
It's far from the best solution but it works for me. If someone can enhance it...

You can try this solution :
[Is there a mean to call Show DialogHost synchronously ?](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/1661)

It consist from code to call the following method

```
methodMessageDialog(string message, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons messageBoxButtons = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK)).
```

This method is async and waits for user button answer, it will block the current method without blocking the UI.

Comment: Please interpret the solution here

Comment: It consist from code to call the methodMessageDialog(string message, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons messageBoxButtons = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK)). This method is async and waits for user button answer, it will block the current method without block the UI.